# Javascript Document Write Inquiry

Tags: javascript, dom-events, document.write

I have been trying many times to write a code using JavaScript events,
so I thought that JavaScript's `document.write` will be somehow similar to
PHP's echo.
Is there any way to force `document.write` to perform an inline write similar to PHP's echo?

The sample: Situation

My website

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" onchange="writeText()">
```

Script

```
<script>
function writeText(){document.write(document.getElementById("inputText").value);}
</script>
```

I want it to act like every time you change the value of the text box, it will display the value of the textbox just below the text box where it came from or much nicer have it executed by using PHP's echo with some how like this:

```
<script>
var inputs = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
function writeText(){document.write("<"."?php "."echo '".inputs."';"."?".">");}
</script>
```

Note: please don't use elements to catch the values, I know it but what I want to aim here is to write inline with `document.write`  without  deleting the other contents of the page.

Comment: I know you don't want to hear it, but you really should use a container, and just use var x= "abc123"; document.getElementById('containerid').innerHTML += x;

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` is not designed for use from event handlers because if the current document has already finished loading (which it has when an event fires), then `document.write()` first clears the current document and then adds new content to the empty document.

To add content to a document after it has already loaded, you need to either modify the innerHTML of an existing element or create new elements and programmatically add them to the page.

In your question, it is not clear where you want the writeText() function to put the content that it generates, but here's an example of append some new content into a document at a particular location in the document.

```
function writeText(parentElem, newHTML) {
    var elem = document.createElement("span");
    elem.innerHTML = newHTML;
    parentElem.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: so there is no way use it like PHP echo? i mean echo can insert new lines in the coding but sadly it in not applicable for javascript? well this is the true reason why i asked it, i want javascript to insert code lines of php without the entire framework. Practically passing variables of javascript to php alongside triggering an event. the whole purpose is to make a datatable dynamically filtering its contents via event triggers like onchange.

Comment: @LynyrdSalita - sorry, but I do not understand what you are trying to do.  Javascript runs in the browser client.  PHP runs on your server.